# Apple's Swift Sprite Kit: linearDamping, how is this property used mathematically?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, velocity

I'm working on a game engine in Java. A while back I was using Sprite Kit with Swift and the property linearDamping is used in the SKPhysicsBody for slowing down the SKPhysicsBody. My question is, how is it used mathematically to reduce the velocity? I have the velocity for my game engine, but I would like to gradually slow down the moving object, but I need to know how the linearDamping property is used for doing so. Any thoughts or knowledge would be great, thanks.

Comment: You can figure that out.  Create some test nodes at various velocities, fire them off with the linearDamping set to 1.0,  record the results.  (Be sure to include the time it took per frame to dampen)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The formula for Box2D is velocity *=  1.0f / (1.0f + time * linearDamping);

Comment: Sorry, I got some of the things wrong (The source uses single letter variables)

Comment: Are Box2D and SpriteKit not two different engines?

Comment: SpriteKit uses Box2D, but a modified version I believe

Comment: @MarkoCrush I updated the formula,  To prove the math,  Let velocity v = 10,  let time = 1, let linearDamping = .2;  v = 10 * 1/(1 + 1 * .2) ; v = 10 * 1 / 1.2; v = 10 * .08333; v = 8.3.  We slowed down by 1.7 units

Comment: Thanks! It's seems to be working now, the velocity reduces over time!

Comment: You are amazing, huge thanks I can finally now confirm that it works! :)

Comment: No problem, thankfully box2d source exists, http://box2d.org/  Maybe you want to just use that in java.

Comment: Yeah, the Sprite Kit documentation had nothing interesting! So Sprite Kit is based on Box2D?

Comment: Yes, SpriteKit uses Box2D,  how much of that is changed is unknown though

Comment: @MarkoCrush can you mark this as the answer,  somebody downvoted this even though it is correct (The person probably downvoted it because they didn't know that Spritekit uses box2d)